# Access ssh of server with dell drac installed

Tags: ssh, dell, drac

I've got a new dell r610 with a DRAC 6 express installed. I've never colocated before nor have I owned a server so pre-apologies for the lack of knowledge.

I'm trying to access my server via SSH on local network however it won't work. The DHCP of my router has assigned the server a local IP. Whenever I try to connect to the server through it's IP for example 192.168.1.45 it connects to the dell iDrac instead. Is there a way to fix this and will it happen on a public IP too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The iDRAC6 Express doesn't have a dedicated card so it uses one of the onboard NICs so I'm guessing that the one you are connected to is the one you 'lose' to iDRAC. Try connecting to a different NIC on the server.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go, however for some reason the linux operating system can still connect to the internet via the same cable so it's a bit strange. I wonder if there is a way to seperate the 2.

Answer (score 0):

I am no Dell user, but most likely it has a dedicated management port for DRAC and you have connected your server only with this port to the network. Connect a non-management port as well and use this to work with the server.

The DRAC is an out-of-band management interface that allows you to control and monitor your server remotely, even without an OS installed.